# htaccess allow access to one PHP file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

My initial .htaccess allows access only to non-php files in a directory:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
<Files ~ ".(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|pdf)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

I want to allow access now to one specific php file (relative path from .htaccess foo/bar/baz.php)

Tried adding

```
<Files foo/bar/baz.php>
  order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

also tried

```
<Files ~ "(baz)$">
  order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

How do I add access for this one file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

<Files ~ "\.(xml|css|jpe?g|png|gif|js|pdf)$">
  Allow from all
</Files>

<Files ~ "baz\.php$">
  Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would also allow access to foo/baz.php, bar/baz.php, etc.

Comment: `<Location>` tag isn't allowed in .htaccess so one cannot match a URI, but `mod_rewrite` can be used for precise path matching.